# Conflicting modules. LoggerFactory is not a Logback LoggerContext but Logback is on the classpath

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, marklogic

I am getting the error found in the title when I try to run my project. I have read other threads on this error, and found a solution that got rid of the error, but killed all my logging.

```
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
```

and

```
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
```

both serve to rid me of the error and kill my logging. I would rather be able to keep my Spring-Boot logging and resolve this problem, but haven't been able to find a solution. Is there a way I can keep my current logging and resolve this dependency issue? What is the best way to track down the offending module?

The full error is:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   LoggerFactory is not a Logback LoggerContext but Logback is on the
>   classpath. Either remove Logback or the competing implementation
>   (class org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory loaded from
>   file:/C:/Users/me/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.6.4/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.4.jar).
>   If you are using WebLogic you will need to add 'org.slf4j' to
>   prefer-application-packages in WEB-INF/weblogic.xml:
>   org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory

edit: the pom:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.marklogic</groupId>
        <artifactId>mlcp</artifactId>
        <version>8.0-4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
        <artifactId>avro</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-modeler</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-modeler</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>11.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-auth</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-yarn-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-yarn-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-xc</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
        <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xerces</groupId>
        <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xpp3</groupId>
        <artifactId>xpp3</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.jena</groupId>
        <artifactId>jena-arq</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.jena</groupId>
        <artifactId>jena-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.jena</groupId>
        <artifactId>jena-iri</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
        <artifactId>solr-commons-csv</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.01</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
        <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-yarn-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.htrace</groupId>
        <artifactId>htrace-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.marklogic</groupId>
        <artifactId>marklogic-xcc</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.marklogic</groupId>
        <artifactId>marklogic-mapreduce2</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: you should show the whole pom as Logback is still present at runtime.

Comment: @davidxxx added the pom

Comment: I'm in a similar boat, but I'm on an dated 10.3.6 version of WebLogic. Figured I'd comment and see if you ever figured it out as I imagine I may end up at the same point with logging broken once I get the app to deploy

Comment: So did you finally manage to fix this issue?

Answer (score 5):

Spring Boot automatically configures the Log Back library because of the web starter. You should exclude the spring-boot-starter-logging to fix the issue.

To exclude the default LogBack configuration in the maven project,

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

[This](https://tedblob.com/loggerfactory-is-not-a-logback-loggercontext-but-logback-is-on-the-classpath/) covers all possible solutions for both Gradle and Maven project.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when deploying Spring boot as a war in wildfly 23

So i resolved the issue by adding the dependencies int the below order.

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>

 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Did you mean to exclude `<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>` ?

Because for me, it was not working. So I completely removed this tag, I was able to deploy of WildFly 27.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

For me the following solution worked on

WindFly 27.0.1
JDK - openjdk version "17.0.5" 2022-10-18 LTS
Apache Maven 3.8.6 (84538c9988a25aec085021c365c560670ad80f63)
Java version: 17.0.5, vendor: Amazon.com Inc., runtime: C:\Program Files\Amazon Corretto\jdk17.0.5_8

Here is the pom:

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-graphql</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webflux</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.graphql</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-graphql-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

You can remove  tag and all the test tags like - spring-boot-starter-test

I am not sure that why did the deployed failed when i removed - `<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>`